# How to make function "onEdit(e) " more specific?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want the event `onEdit(e)`  to  trigger only when their is a change in specific column and not in the whole spread-sheet.

also, is their any way to return the value of the cell on wish the change has been made ?

Thanx!

Comment: Yes...my mistake

Answer (score 2):

Add a `if` condition:

```
function onEdit(e) {
if (e.range.getColumn() == 2) { //If edited column is 2 or `B` column
//your code here
}
}
```

To get the value of edited range, You may use

```
e.range.getValue()
```

or

```
e.value
```

The latter will only work,If only one cell is edited.

Ref:

[Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)

[Range Obj](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range)

Comment: Im getting the error "TypeError: Cannot read property "range" from undefined. (line 45, file "Code")Dismiss"

Comment: ok...so i should change '2' to 'B'? or it convert b to 2?
actually i need the column J

Comment: so here's my code but it dont call the function for smone resaon -->


function onEdit(e) 
{
  if (e.range.getColumn() == 10) 
  { 
    personColumnChanged(e);
  }
}

Comment: ok, i have looked there but im still having problems.

here is my onEdit Func --- function

 onEdit(e) 
{
  personColumnChanged(e);
 
}

and the other function ---


function personColumnChanged(e) 
  {
  
    messageit('mesage sent);
    sendText('429730839', 'asdasd');    

  }

the messageit function triggered but the other function sendText didnt trigered